# SharePoint workflow dynamic link to "Submitters" Display form

Tags: workflow

Hello I have a SP workflow question for you gurus out there.

I have a list, that among other items contains a “Submitter” field and a Status Field.  I have created a workflow that sends an email to the “Submitter” when his list items “Status field” changes to Approved. This is working as it should.  What I need to do is in the body of the email, create a link that links to the Display Form of that particular Submitter’s line item. Meaning that when the email is generated, that link would automatically change based on the Submitter receiving it, so that Submitter will seeing the link to his Display Form.  The link is not static, has to be dynamic based on the Submitter who receives it.  Hope that makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: is a sharepoint designer workflow?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a SharePoint workflow designer , you can add the related list item URL

1. in define E-mail Message window **click Add or Change Lookup**
2. in the Data source dropdown select **Workflow Context**
3. in the Field from the source select **Current Item Url**

[image]